# Bidirectional communication on stdin/stdout from container to host?

Tags: docker, unix-socket, socat

I'm building a development Docker image I intend to run on my local machine. On this image I want to put two programs; I'll call them `progA` and `progB`. I am not the author of these programs, so I cannot change how they communicate. Both programs can only send & receive data on stdin/stdout.

I have a third program—`progC`—that I want to run on my host. `progC` needs to communicate with both `progA` and `progB` independently (meaning `progC`⇔`progA` and `progC`⇔`progB`) using stdin/stdout.

While I'm definitely a n00b when it comes to `socat`, [from what I've read](https://copyconstruct.medium.com/socat-29453e9fc8a6) I feel like this should be possible. This is my mental model so far:

**Inside the container**: Establish a bidirectional connection between `progA` and a TCP port. Do the same for `progB` using a different port.

**On the host**: Run the Docker container publishing the ports to the host. Have a local script that—when invoked—binds the ports to stdin/stdout. There will be a script for `progA` and another for `progB`. `progC` will control when either script is invoked, and the binding created from the script should remain open and active until `progC` terminates the script.

---

Is this possible? If so, how? Is this advisable? If not, is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Are TCP sockets required? Having programs talk over stdin and stdout doesn't require networking. If I'm understanding this right, I think you could get the programs connected to each other using plain UNIX pipes without any networking or TCP. Or maybe you mean something different than stdin/stdout when you said "stdio" throughout?

Comment: ("stdio" is the name of C's standard I/O library. It's only relevant if you're editing C code that calls `printf()` and `scanf()` such. When looking at a process from the outside "stdio" isn't the right term.)

Comment: The networking is required because the programs aren't running on the same "system": `progA` and `progB` are running inside of a Docker container, and `progC` is running on the Docker host. I tried using unix domain sockets initially, but Docker can only bind mount files from host -> container, not container -> host. Since the thing I needed to talk to is created from within the container, I needed an alternate interface. I guessed named/anonymous pipes would suffer the same limitation as the unix sockets, but I didn't actually test that.

Comment: [The description for the `stdio` SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdio/info) threw me, since it ends with "or using the standard streams stdin, stdout, stderr" which I didn't interpret as being C-specific but referring to shell's STDIN & STDOUT—apologies about that!

Comment: Docker containers can use stdin, stdout, and named pipes, and UNIX sockets just like regular processes. You should definitely give those another look, in that order of preference. For example, all containers can write to stdout, and `docker run -i` will leave stdin open if they need to read input. To use a named pipe you would create it on the host and then bind it into the container, then host and container can both access the pipe. UNIX sockets are similar. You may have seen `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` before, a common trick to let containers access the host's UNIX socket.

Comment: Thanks. The trick is that you need to create or bind to something on the host  *before* running the container; in my case the processes in the container create the interfaces I'm interested in consuming (stdin/stdout, named pipe, socket, whatever) from the host. I don't really want to create those manually on the host before running the container—that somewhat defeats the ergonomics I'm after with this container.

Comment: I know Docker containers can use stdin and stdout—which would work for me if I were only running one process inside the container. I want to run *two* processes inside the same container that both listen on stdin independently, thus the question.

Answer (score 2):

Think I figured it out:

On the provider (container) side (for `progA`):

```
socat -dd SYSTEM:progA TCP-LISTEN:3344,forever,reuseaddr
```

On the consumer (host) side:

```
socat -/!/!STDOUT TCP:localhost:3344
```

I plop that second value in to `progC` as the command it needs to run to talk to `progA` over `stdin`, and it works! `socat` is pretty magical!